# Pandas Translating column data to new columns following date

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, transformation

Here is a sample of my dataset (7 columns) :

```
ID_CPTE     PERIODID_MY     CurrentTotalBalance CashBalance CreditLimit DelqCycle   TRANSACTION_AMT
99690111    2015-05-01      8497.84             4293.12     16200       0           176.8
99690111    2014-11-01      866                 0           12000       0           0
99690111    2015-06-01      10790.95            5224.44     16200       0           303
99690111    2015-10-01      12388.46            4786.08     16200       0           244.8
99690111    2015-11-01      12746.5             4818.48     16200       0           250
99690111    2015-08-01      10610.05            4753.35     16200       0           267.5
99690111    2015-09-01      11417.12            4616.46     16200       0           226.6
99690111    2014-12-01      1151.85             0           12000       0           0
99690111    2015-02-01      4045.67             1148.45     16200       0           303
99690111    2015-12-01      13119.6             4791.44     16200       0           273
99690111    2015-01-01      2298.96             350         12000       0           262.5
99690111    2015-03-01      5926.2              2567.25     16200       0           200
99690111    2015-04-01      6916.62             3307.33     16200       0           288.8
99690111    2015-07-01      10560               5127.54     16200       0           618
57427180    2011-12-01      219                 0           2800        0           0
57427180    2012-01-01      233.58              236.08      2800        0           494.6
57427180    2012-02-01      234                 0           2800        0           0
57427180    2012-03-01      809.12              0           2800        1           0
57427180    2012-04-01      1058.84             1.01        2800        2           1076.25
57427180    2012-05-01      260                 0           2800        0           454.5
57427180    2012-06-01      210.08              0           2800        0           412
57427180    2012-07-01      416                 0           2800        0           884
57427180    2012-08-01      243.41              0           2800        0           252.5
57427180    2012-09-01      410.88              0           2800        0           393.9
57427180    2012-10-01      489.72              0           2800        0           476.89
57427180    2012-11-01      689.52              20          2800        0           0
57427180    2012-12-01      266.06              0           2800        0           0
```

Here is what i want to produce using pandas (54 columns (1+13+13+1+13+13)) :

```
ID_CPTE     CurrentTotalBalance_month_[1-13]    CashBalance_month_[1-13]    CreditLimit         DelqCycle_month_[1-13]  TRANSACTION_AMT_month_[1-13]
99690111    ..                                  ..                          CreditLimitAverage  ..                      ..
57427180    ..                                  ..                          CreditLimitAverage  ..                      ..
```

- My goal is to group the data by ID_CPTE while still keeping
  the detail of each month from the original dataset.
- The tricky part is that the data can have 13 or 14 month history, so
  I would only like to capture the last 13 month and create new columns
  from it. I would also like the data to be ordered by date, so
  ..._month_1 would be the oldest record while ..._month_13 would be
  the most recent.
- PERIODID_MY can range from 2011-01-01 to 2016-12-01

Since I am still learning pandas, I am not sure how I should do this transformation and I don't even really know from where to start. Can you guys help me figure it out. I am not necessarily hoping anyone will do it for me, but some tips would be much appreciated!

Comment: Do you want to summarize the data or just sort it? Take a look at the groupby documentation at http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html and see if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Summarize it in a way that keeps the detail and in a good format to feed in machine leaning after. I'll check it!